# Use of "Poke" as Victorian slang in Fingersmith

Tags: meaning, historical-context, sarah-waters, fingersmith

Sarah Waters' award-winning Victorian crime novel Fingersmith makes liberal use of period underworld slang. Indeed the title is such slang for a petty thief. Most of it is unfamiliar to the modern reader but easy to understand from the context.

My curiosity was piqued by the unfamiliar language and I started looking some of it up to find the derivation. One phrase, however, I can't source at all: "poke" to mean stolen goods.

> For out from their coats and sleeves would come pocket-books, silk handkerchiefs, petticoats - whole suits of clothes, sometimes. 'This is quality stuff, this is' they would say, as they set it all out; and Mr Ibbs would rub his hands and look expectant. But then he would study their **poke**, and his face would fall.

The only relationship for this meaning I could find is that "poke" is an old-fashioned word for pocket, and most of the thievery in Fingersmith is pickpocketry.

> poke
>   n. Chiefly Southern US
>   A sack; a bag.

In-context use in the book, however, suggests the word means goods stolen by any means, not just picking pockets. And the US derivation makes it a stretch for Victorian London.

Can anyone confirm whether this meaning is genuine Victorian slang and where the author found this unfamiliar usage?

Comment: Not sure if I quite understand the context. Could it mean "money", as in [this slang dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA904&lpg=PA904&dq=%22poke%22+london+slang)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor It may be related but it's not direct - look at the quote from the book where "poke" is used to describe stolen perfume. In another early example, it clearly means some stolen candlesticks. I can add the quote if you like?

Comment: So it means roughly "swag", to use a more modern slang term?

Comment: Surely she’s calling the bag ‘poor’ as a way of saying it’s value is low, in the same way the amount of game birds taken at a shoot would be described as ‘the bag’.  Btw ‘poke’ is still used to mean bag in central Scotland.

Comment: @Spagirl Yes, but I'm interested in where the use of "poke" to mean something stolen comes from, and whether it's accurate. I may replace that example quote with something clearer, as it seems to have confused Rand al'Thor too

Comment: @MattThrower That's clearer. There is certainly nothing in the OED or the 1811 Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue which suggests the usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sense of the word is not in the *OED*, but Eric Partridge has it:

> **Poke**. 1. Stolen property: from ca. 1850; ob. *The Times*, Nov 29, 1860; Baumann. Ex *poke*, a bag, pocket, etc.
>
> <sub>Eric Partridge (1923). [*A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, fifth edition. p. 644](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.460523/page/n651). London: Routledge & Kegan Paul.</sub>

I don’t have access to the *Times* archive, but evidently the report was syndicated for it can be found in other newspapers via the [British Newspaper Archive](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk):

> Langley deposed that he apprehended Rees at his lodgings. He was in bed with a young woman who lives with him as his wife. (He is about 16 or 17 years of age.) While dressing himself, he asked, “Did you find the **‘poke’ (booty)** at the old man’s?” Witness made no answer.
>
> <sub>*London Evening Standard*. Thursday, November 29, 1860.</sub>

Baumann’s dictionary of London slang is available via the Internet Archive:

> **poke 1. c)** Gestohlenes, Beute: **the ~ had been got away** der Raub war beiseite geschafft worden.
>
> <sub>Heinrich Baumann (1887). [*Londinismen, Slang und Cant*, p. 141](https://archive.org/details/londinismenslan00baumgoog/page/n252). Berlin: Langenscheidtsche.</sub>

‘Gestohlenes’ = stolen property; ‘Beute’ = booty, loot.

Answer (score 2):

What about 'a pig in a poke' If pokes were only small like wallets you couldn't get a pig in one. So I assume that the term should also apply to a larger item a sort of 'swag bag'

Comment: Could you expand on your actual answer to the question? It looks like there's an answer buried in here, but your post looks almost like a new question as well.